# Error while importing Maven Project into Eclipse

Tags: spring, maven

if i Give resolve later and go into the eclipse i get the error in the Pom.xml

```
Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:pom:2.5 from http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. 
Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:pom:2.5 
from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): null to http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/2.5/maven-resources-plugin-2.5.pom
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your local `.m2` folder (c:\users\.m2), select the directory `org\apache\maven\plugins\maven-resources-plugin`, delete it.

Then use in eclipse `<project-root>\maven\Update Project...`

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes Maven fails to download the dependencies properly.

You can right click on the project, and select `Maven->Update Project`. Then make sure the `Force Update of Snapshot/Releases` check box is selected and press `OK`.